# How to mark a list item as read?

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have created app that shows info about movies. Now, the problem is I cannot set a mark or make title as bold whenever user clicks on listview item. So, user can know which movies he/she watched.
I added boolean variable in getView() method but this did not help to solve problem.
 This is [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y7irL20VgufqtsL66lfDBJ6tzqY7P7bP/view?usp=sharing) of my app :

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CustomAdapter myadapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int[] images = {R.drawable.dfg,R.drawable.godf,R.drawable.godf2,R.drawable.thedark,R.drawable.twelv,R.drawable.shindl};
    String[] movie_titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Movie_titles);
    String[] movie_ratings=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Movie_ratings);
    String[] movie_janrs=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Movie_janrs);
    int[] arrows = {R.drawable.hjk,R.drawable.hjk,R.drawable.hjk,R.drawable.hjk,R.drawable.hjk,R.drawable.hjk};
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    myadapter = new CustomAdapter(this,images,movie_titles,movie_ratings,movie_janrs,arrows);
    if(mylist!=null){
        mylist.setAdapter(myadapter);
    }
    mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position==0){
                Intent movie1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MovieOne.class);
                startActivity(movie1);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
static LayoutInflater vi=null;
int[] images;
String[] movie_titles;
String[] movie_ratings;
String[] movie_janrs;
int[] arrows;


public CustomAdapter(Context context, int images[], String movie_titles[], String movie_ratings[], String movie_janrs[],int arrows[]){
    this.context = context;
    this.images=images;
    this.movie_titles=movie_titles;
    this.movie_ratings=movie_ratings;
    this.movie_janrs=movie_janrs;
    this.arrows=arrows;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movie_titles.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView ==null){
         vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         convertView=vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
    }
    if(convertView!=null){
        ImageView tvImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.one);
        TextView tvTittle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.two);
        TextView tvRating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.three);
        TextView tvJanr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.four);
        ImageView tvImage2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.six);
        if(tvImage!=null && tvTittle!=null && tvRating!=null && tvJanr!=null){
            tvImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
            tvTittle.setText(movie_titles[position]);
            tvRating.setText(movie_ratings[position]);
            tvJanr.setText(movie_janrs[position]);
            tvImage2.setImageResource(arrows[position]);
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

**MovieOne.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MovieOne extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.movie_one);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For list item click or read, you have to maintain the position of item click.

```
OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                mSelectedItem = position;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

and in your `getView()` method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

        if (position == mSelectedItem) {
            // set your color
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

create 'clicked' array of boolean type with length of movie_titles; initialize all items to false and pass it to your adapter. In your getView when you click item, get its position and set clicked item to true